# Rails 5 routes error (missing required keys: [:id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"items", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

from this route:

```
resources :items do
    member do
      get :search
    end
end
```

and this is the form I have in the view:

```
<%= form_tag search_item_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: 'Enter keyword' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `search_item_path` is used without an `id` parameter.

The path is defined on a member. In the routes context, a member will mean an individual resource not the collection of resources. Individual members are referenced by their id typically. Your form should thus look like this:

```
<%= form_tag search_item_path([SOME ID YOU HAVE TO PROVIDE]), method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: 'Enter keyword' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil  %>
<% end %>
```

**Update after comments by OP**

I now believe that the form is not your problem after all, but rather the routes. If you want to search on the items based on some term that the routes should be set up like this:

```
resources :items do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Notice that I changed `member` to `collection` compared to the routes shown in the question. You should then be able to use your form unaltered compared to what is shown in the question (no id necessary) then.

You also might want to reuse the index action already set up by the resource definition. Filtering on an index action is quite common.

You can take a [look at the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @uferst... I did this `<%= form_tag search_item_path([id: @item.id]), method: :get do %>` and it retuns this: `undefined method id for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I changed the routes according to the code and this is what happens, on the console the items seems to be loaded, but for some reason don't show on the view page. `Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (title = 'table' or description = 'table') ORDER BY created_at DESC` please check my question form more info, I have updated it.

Comment: @Dev, please check if you have values in the db by running `Item.search('table').order("created_at DESC")` in the console `rails c`

Comment: It returns this: `Item Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (title = 'table' or description = 'table') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `

Comment: @Dev, this looks as if you do not have any items in the DB and hence it is correct that no items are rendered. Can you take a look inside the db via a sql tool to check if that is true?

Comment: `rails dbconsole` and then what command do use to take a look?

Comment: Please close this question and open a new one as this question's focus is diluting

Answer (score 1):

If your have a `@item` object, use:

```
<%= form_tag search_item_path(@item), method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: 'Enter keyword' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil  %>
<% end %>
```

or:

```
<%= form_tag search_item_path(id: @item.id), method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: 'Enter keyword' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil  %>
<% end %>
```

---

Looks like you just wan't to pass a search query. Why include the search route in member ?

Try putting it out:

```
resources :items
get '/items/search', to: "items#search"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Graham Slick... `The first one is returning: No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"items", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]` and the second one is returning: `undefined method id for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Yes because the @item object is nil. Show more code. What's the object you're trying to edit with this form ?

Comment: It's a search form not an edit form, I want to search for items.

Comment: Thanks it works @Graham Slick... and if I want to make this route a `root route` I just do this: `root 'items#search'` and I just access it via the `form_tag` like this: `<%= form_tag root_path, method: :get do %>`